# Which is better in performance aspect :remotely MySQL DB , store data in form of xml , json while working with android

Tags: android, mysql, xml, json, performance

I've just started my app in android.And i want my app should not consume much CPU of device.
I have 3 choice for data accessing .
1 . MySQL Database on remote server.
2 . Data stored in form of xml on remote server
3 . Data stored in form of json on remote server.

Data is approx 2000-3000 rows in database.
Which approach should i use for better performance of my app.

Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: I am waiting for useful suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How your data is stored on the remote server is of little concern to the android app. The real  question is how it's transferred, and how you handle and store it locally.

With this much data, your best bet is to use to stream the data and parse the stream. For XML, that would mean using the SAX parser, for JSON probably streaming [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/). JSON uses less bandwidth and Jackson is hands-down the fastest way to churn through formatted data.

Streaming has the obvious advantage that you do not need to keep all this data in memory to parse as DOM, but it comes at the cost of a higher development effort.

Locally, the best way to store this amount of data would be a sqlite database, which you can easily query.

Comment: If i use , json for that and when data comes at user's device than after that i have to convert that data into tabular form so that it can store into local SQLLite database??? I was thinking that it would be better managed that data as cache.

Comment: You can do whatever fits the data best. You said the data had 2K-3K rows, so I assumed it's in table form already -- all you need to do is write it. If you store it as JSON locally, then you either need to parse each time you access it, or build a DOM each time the program runs. The repeated parsing is going to be slow, and building a DOM for 3K rows is going to use a bit of memory. So storing it in sqlite solves both those issues for you.